# Phonegap CLI adding Android fails

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

I have trolled through the question related to this problem but still no go.

I have tried.

Made sure API level is 19, 
Made sure the path is set,
Made sure dependencies are installed.

Getting started using [this guide](http://www.simdroids.com/getting-started-with-phonegap-using-cli/) (ubuntu)

This command `sudo cordova platform add android` results in ...

```
/home/username/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
 Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
at /home/username/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:87:29
at _rejected (/home/username/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
at /home/username/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
at Promise.when (/home/username/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/username/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
at /home/username/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
at flush (/home/username/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
Error: /home/username/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)
```

Comment: Are you sure that `ant` is installed on the system? That is a common issue with android and phonegap.

Comment: sudo apt-get -u install ant
[sudo] password for username: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ant is already the newest version.

Comment: `$ nodejs -v
v0.10.8
 npm -v
1.2.23
`

Comment: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on August 19 2011

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to use sudo to add platforms or to use any of the Cordova/PhoneGap commands. You only need sudo when installing cordova.

What happens when you issue the 'android' command from the command line? It should load the Android tools. If that doesn't happen, then none of the Android related Cordova command line stuff will work.

You need ant on the path as well as the adt /tools and /platform-tools folders on the system path. That's the minimum requirement for Android Cordova development.

John M. Wargo
www.cordovaprogramming.com, www.cordovacookbook.com

Comment: Either with or without sudo doesn't have a good result.

Android does indeed load the android tools

username@gahn:~/phonegap/hello$ which ant

/usr/bin/ant

username@gahn:~/phonegap/hello$ which npm

/usr/bin/npm

username@gahn:~/phonegap/hello$ which git

/usr/bin/git

Comment: OK, what happens when you issue an: android list avd?  Does it give you a list of ADVs defined on your system? You have to have at least one defined before you can do the platform add command.